# incrementing the variable on for loop

Tags: javascript

```
var Top = 5;
for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    var Model = createView("First ModelView", Top, 135);        
}
```

Initially the Top = 5, for each iterating the Top should get added
 with another +50, so that the next time it should create an Model Object with 
Top 55 and so on...

**What i tried**

```
var Top = 5;
for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    var Model = createView("First ModelView", Top, 135); 
    Top+=50;        
}
```

Comment: What went wrong with your second code sample?  At first glance, it looks OK.  What was the the unexpected result?

Comment: You are assigning something to Model and then in the next loop iteration, overwriting the variable (depending on what createView does, this may be OK).  And, the var Model does not exist outside the for loop so why do you even have it?

Comment: Please describe the issue you're having. The expected result vs the result are you getting. This is obviously not your complete code. Perhaps you could post code that more fully illustrates what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
  var Model = createView("First ModelView", 5+i*50, 135);       
}
```

(assuming you just want to have a 50 increment with a 5 base for first case)

Answer (score 3):

Or just put the desired result right into the for loop

```
for (var i=5; i<155; i+=50) {
  createView("First ModelView", i, 135);       
}
```

And, there doesn't seem to be much point to assigning to the `var Model` since you're not using it and all iterations through the loop assign to the same variable.